# Showing IPhone keyboard in different languages based on user input

Tags: iphone, objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.0

My question is related to the following question, and can be said almost same.

[Setting the iPhone keyboard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language)

But here are my requirement. I am writing dictionary app for IPhone, which support multiple languages. So my requirement is to display the English keyboard when user has selected English language and show Dutch keyboard when user has selected Dutch and so on.

So i was wondering if this is possible?

I have a hunch that if i "internationalize" the nib, it will display the respective keyboard but not sure.

Thanks.

Comment: I have created several custom iOS keyboards that work great, you may eventually want to go that route

Comment: @Cirrostratus 

I think you are right, look like there is no other way. Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you cannot control the language of the keyboard.  The user chooses which keyboards they would like available via the settings application and can toggle between them using the globe icon on the keyboard.  When the keyboard is opened it will open to the most recently used keyboard.

Comment: But maybe current keyboard's language stored to user defaults?

Answer (score -3):

What developers need to do in order to create an internationalized app using localized strings:

Basically you create the localized strings for the languages you want to support:

```
//Localizable.String file for the English version.
"WelcomeKey" = "Welcome!!!";
//Localizable.strings file for the Italian version.
"WelcomeKey" = "Benvenuto!!!";
```

Then use them in the app:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application {

NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSArray *languages = [defaults objectForKey:@"AppleLanguages"];
NSString *currentLanguage = [languages objectAtIndex:0];

NSLog(@"Current Locale: %@", [[NSLocale currentLocale] localeIdentifier]);
NSLog(@"Current language: %@", currentLanguage);
NSLog(@"Welcome Text: %@", NSLocalizedString(@"WelcomeKey", @""));

// Override point for customization after application launch
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Users can change the language for the keyboard in the settings on the iphone
Settings->General->International

Comment: It doesn't solve the problem. First, it is not thing that user can switch easily like for dictionary. Secondly, it doesn't change your keyboard

Comment: Well the problem is about keyboard, not localization.

Comment: @itsaboutcode, Funny thing that your username is about code, too.