# Change language of keyboard

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, keyboard

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Setting the iPhone keyboard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language)

In my iPhone app, I want to change the language of the keyboard from English to Chinese Simplified in code. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible and intended by Apple I think. [The same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language) has been asked before but hasn't been answered so far, but the posts indicate that it is not possible. You can search around more to see that changing the language by code seems impossible:

- [Showing IPhone keyboard in different languages based on user input.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032116/showing-iphone-keyboard-in-different-languages-based-on-user-input)
- [How to change iPhone app language during runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576904/how-to-change-iphone-app-language-during-runtime)

Comment: thanks but i need to change if anyone help me then i'll be thankful

Comment: if "the same question has been asked before", please vote to close as duplicate rather than answering.

Comment: @Josh Caswell The problem is, there is an exact duplicate with no accepted answer and some which are related to changing the language by code but not in context of a keyboard so I am uncertain.

Comment: Then, in my opinion, you should post a comment with that information.