# Popup japanese keyboard in iphone

Tags: iphone, iphone-softkeyboard

Can we change the keyboard language in iPhone from English to Japanese programatically?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing keyboard programmatically is not doable in iOS

Similar answers [Change language of keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907642/change-language-of-keyboard)

Comment: Thanks for the quick respond Omar.