# Is this possible to force the iOS keyboard pop the English keyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch

If the user have more than one keyboard on their iOS devices. Is this possible to force to pop the English keyboard? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From [Text Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW5),

> The input method and layout for the keyboard is determined by the user’s language preferences

There is no way afaik to force the language programmatically.

- [Setting the iPhone keyboard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language)
- [Change language of keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5907642/change-language-of-keyboard)

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

To implement the language preferences of different users, iOS also supports different input methods and keyboard layouts for different languages, some of which are shown in Figure 5-2. The input method and layout for the keyboard is determined by the user’s language preferences. Input for some of these keyboards takes place in multiple stages

[image]

more

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html