# Restricting Hindi keyboardType through application

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextview

I want to restrict Hindi keyboardType from any textfield or textview throughout my application. Is there any way I can achieve this by writing code in one place only?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21848872/is-this-possible-to-force-the-ios-keyboard-pop-the-english-keyboard

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik thanks for your response, but it does not resolve my purpose. I need a way by which I can either override a method of UITextField/UITextView or I can write a common method which will be used throughout the app.