# How to switch iPhone keyboard layout?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, layout, iphone-softkeyboard

I have an app which has two different languages (English-German). You can switch within the app between the languages. My question now is, how to switch the keyboard as well? Not just the language but the keyboard layout. Both keyboard language layouts already available within the system, I just don't know how to switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

Go through the following post, will helpful for you

[image]

[Change Your Keyboard or Display Language in iOS](http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/)

[Setting the iPhone keyboard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language)