# Display the swedish keypad for iphone

Tags: iphone, keyboard

I want to open the swedish keypad for UITextField.How can i achieve this?Should i customize the keypad?

Need help on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not achieve opening **swedish keypad** programmatically, Check the below link for more info.

[image]

[Change Your Keyboard or Display Language in iOS](http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/)

[Setting the iPhone keyboard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language)

[Taken from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6186104/how-to-switch-iphone-keyboard-layout/6186153#6186153)