# Keypad language change during runtime?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

At runtime for the app, I want the user to be able to select the keypad language.  And when the app is finished for it to switch back.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could not do it programmatically but there is one option is available in keyboard itself.

Go through the following post, will helpful for you

[image]

[Change Your Keyboard or Display Language in iOS](http://iphone.appstorm.net/how-to/change-your-keyboard-or-display-language-in-ios/)

[Setting the iPhone keyboard language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/330542/setting-the-iphone-keyboard-language)

Comment: Thank you for your help. Good to learn this.  But I have to assume that the class has to be out there to do at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is a programmatic way to enforce this. You can inplemet your own custom input if you want.